# Rename specific sheet from specific folder sub folders

Tags: excel, vba

I have several excel files in folder & want to rename only specific sheets of every file in the folder which contains

viz. GTLB, SALARY, GROC

Every file has a single sheet of above characters, other sheets have different names.
So, if sheet name contains above characters then change it to **GROCERY**.

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, does your folder contain Excel files only, or other file types as well? Concerning the Excel files, are they all the same Excel file ending (e.g., .xlsx), or different versions of Excel/types of Excel files? Please provide as much information as possible along with your question soe the community can help you.

Comment: All files are *.xls only in all folders & I want to rename only specific sheet which are having text as 'GTLB' / 'SALARY' / 'GROC' change to 'GROCERY'

Answer (score 0):

Try using this it will loop through the folder try finding files (excel files) and try looking for the strings in files that have been specified and if match  found change the name.

```
  Sub LoopThroughFiles()
 'loops through all files in a folder
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim path As String
Dim st As String

file = Dir("H:\TestCopy\testing\") 'file name
path = "H:\TestCopy\testing\" 'directory path

While (file <> "")
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("H:\TestCopy\testing\" & file)
     MsgBox "found " & file
    ' path = path & file 'path and filename
     Call newloopTrhoughBooks
     wbk.Save
     wbk.Close
   ' Call loop_through_all_worksheets(path)
 file = Dir
Wend
End Sub

 Sub newloopTrhoughBooks()
 Dim book As Workbook, sheet As Worksheet, text As String, text1 As String
  Dim logic_string As String
   Dim logic_string2 As String
  Dim logic_string3 As String

   logic_string = "GTLB"
    logic_string2 = "SALARY"
    logic_string3 = "GROC"

   For Each book In Workbooks
  text = text & "Workbook: " & book.Name & vbNewLine & "Worksheets: " &   vbNewLine

  For Each sheet In book.Worksheets
  text = text & sheet.Name & vbNewLine
  text1 = sheet.Name
   If StrComp(logic_string, text1) = 1 Or StrComp(logic_string2, text1) = 1 Or StrComp(logic_string3, text1) = 1 Then 'compare file name
  ActiveSheet.Name = text1
  ActiveSheet.Name = "Change1"
  End If
  Next sheet
 text = text & vbNewLine
 Next book
MsgBox text

 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for reply Your code changing the name of default 1st sheet which doesn't contain 'GTLB' / 'SALARY' / 'GROC'. I want to rename only the sheet which have 'GTLB' / 'SALARY' / 'GROC' in the name

Comment: if that's works fine for you all you need to do is change this line of code to reference what you need  `logic_string = "GTLB"`  and you can have three variables and compare all of them like so here `If StrComp(logic_string, c.Name) OR  StrComp(logic_string1, c.Name) Then`  so  on for the other substrings you want to find

Comment: Hi Tim, your code showing & I have changed as per your suggestion but facing Run Time Error 432 : File Name or Class Name not found during automation operation..... at line Set sh = GetObject(file).Worksheets
........ Actually your code changing the name of first sheet of file no. 1 & kept opened not get closed... There are 5 - 6 sheets in every file & one of them is having text 'GTLB' / 'SALARY' / 'GROC' in the sheet name...... I want to renamed that sheet to  'GROCERY'. as well as in every file there is only one sheet among 5-6 sheets which is having the text in their name NOT the First One

Comment: up dated that to work with your specification have a play you might need to tell your code not to process the workbook with the code if it is not to be processed

Comment: I am not that much familiar with code but on this site I found this ... Can we alter this as per our requirement.... How I can add code though it have length more than specified character limit.

Comment: See this code I found . Can we change it as per requirement ....**bold**    `code` Sub RenSheets()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wbname As String
MyFolder = "C:\example"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
    With ActiveWorkbook
        wbname = Left(.Name, InStr(.Name, ".") - 1)
        .Sheets(1).Name = wbname
        .Close savechanges:=True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub    `code`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RenameSheets()
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wbname As String

MyFolder = "E:\SSS\File Name"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While MyFile <> ""

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
    With ActiveWorkbook
        wbname = "GROCERY"
'For giving filename to sheet1
       'Left(.Name, InStr(.Name, ".") - 1)
        For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If LCase(sheet.Name) Like "*salary*" Or LCase(sheet.Name) Like "*gtlb*" Or LCase(sheet.Name) Like "*groc*" Then
        MsgBox "Found! " & sheet.Name
         .Sheets(sheet.Name).Name = wbname
          .Close savechanges:=True
    End If
Next
       '.Sheets(1).Name = wbname
        '.Close savechanges:=True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```